# Avoiding HTTP "too many requests" error when using SPARQLWrapper and Wikidata

Tags: http, sparql, wikidata, http-status-code-429, sparqlwrapper

I have a list of approximately 6k wikidata instance IDs (beginning Q#####) I want to look up the human-readable labels for. I am not too familiar with SPARQL, but following some guidelines have managed to find a query that works for a single ID.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

query = """
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
    SELECT *
    WHERE {
            wd: Q##### rdfs:label ?label .
            FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ) )
          }
    LIMIT 1
    """

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://query.wikidata.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery(query)
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
output = sparql.query().convert()
```

I had hoped that iterating over a list of IDs would be as simple as putting the IDs in a dataframe and using the apply function...

```
ids_DF['label'] = ids_DF['instance_id'].apply(my_query_function)
```

... However, when I do that it errors out with a **"HTTPError: Too Many Requests"** warning. Looking into the documentation, specifically the [query limits](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Query_limits) section, it says the following:

> Query limits

> There is a hard query deadline configured which is set to 60 seconds. There are also following limits:
>
> - One client (user agent + IP) is allowed 60 seconds of processing time each 60 seconds
> - One client is allowed 30 error queries per minute

I'm unsure how to go about resolving this. Am I looking to run 6k error queries (i'm unsure what an error query even is)? In which case I presumably need to run them in batches to avoid going over the 30 second window.

My first attempt to resolve this was been to put a delay of 2 seconds after each query (see third from last line below). I noticed that each instance ID was taking approximately 1 second to return a value so my thinking was that a delay would boost the amount of time taken to 3 seconds (which should comfortably keep me within the limit). However, that still returns the same error. I've tried extending this sleep period as well, with the same results.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

query = """
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
    SELECT *
    WHERE {
            wd: Q##### rdfs:label ?label .
            FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ) )
          }
    LIMIT 1
    """

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://query.wikidata.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery(query)
time.sleep(2) # imported from time
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
output = sparql.query().convert()
```

A similar question on this topic was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396801/how-to-handle-too-many-requests-on-wikidata-using-sparqlwrapper) but I've not been able to follow the advice given.

Comment: instead of doing 6K queries you should simply run just a few queries with the Wikidata entities provided in a batch. SPARQL `VALUES` clause is the way to go. Maybe 60 queries with 100 entities provided in each query, you can try what works best. And don't forget to make it a POST request as the query length might become to large otherwise for GET. To avoid cases with multiple Egnlish labels (are there any for rdfs:label?) you can workaround this using the Wikidata specific label service.

Comment: Your code isn’t specifying a custom user agent (SPARLWrapper agent= constructor argument). Requests without a proper user agent – in violation of the user-agent policy (https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) – may be throttled beyond the documented limits that you found.